# Cmusphinx Spanish model incoherent transcription

Tags: c, wav, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have installed pocketsphinx in my laptop (Linux Mint 17) aiming to transcribe a WAV audio file to text. The audios are in Spanish, so I've downloaded the Voxforge 0.2 Spanish model from its website and copy-pasted-adapted the following code:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ps_decoder_t *ps;
   cmd_ln_t *config;
   FILE *fh;
   char const *hyp, *uttid;
   int16 buf[512];
   int rv;
   int32 score;

   if( argc == 2 ) 
   {
      printf("Transcribiendo fichero: %s\n", argv[1]);
   }
   else if( argc > 2 ) 
   {
      printf("Demasiados argumentos.\n");
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Se esperaba un sólo argumento.\n");
   }
   config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", "/home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/model_parameters/voxforge_es_sphinx.cd_ptm_3000",
             "-lm", "/home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/etc/voxforge_es_sphinx.transcription.test.lm",
             "-dict", "/home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/etc/voxforge_es_sphinx.dic",
             NULL);
   if (config == NULL) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
    return -1;
   }

   ps = ps_init(config);
   if (ps == NULL) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
      return -1;
   }

   fh = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   if (fh == NULL) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file.\n");
      return -1;
   }

   rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

   while (!feof(fh)) 
   {
      size_t nsamp;
      nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
      rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
   }

   rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
   hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
   printf("Reconocido: %s\n", hyp);

   fclose(fh);
   ps_free(ps);
   cmd_ln_free_r(config);

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that a WAV mono 16Khz file yields weird results. 
What I want to know is if I need to rebuild the model or to tune a specific parameter...

For example, considering the following text:

"Hola soy ingeniero informático"

I converted it to a 16KHz/16bits/mono WAV file.

Running my code, it gives this output:

```
> ./nlptest voice.wav
"cola salir en y era de líneas"
```

As you can see it is totally different from the original. Only the words "hola" and "cola" are similar in pronunciation (but absolutely different meaning).

Even using pocketsphinx_continuous, the results are very bad (it only differs in one word):

```
> pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/model_parameters/voxforge_es_sphinx.cd_ptm_3000 -lm /home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/etc/voxforge_es_sphinx.transcription.test.lm -dict /home/<myuser>/software/voxforge-es/etc/voxforge_es_sphinx.dic -infile voice.wav
"cola seguir en y era de líneas"
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I am not sure now, I am perhaps wrong, but I think Sphinx can translate very good only word by word. So, try splitting your wav to separate words. You can do it programmatically by searching for mini pauses between them in an audio. But I am most certainly wrong. Although, you can try it for cupple of words to see whether it will work or not.

Comment: @Dalen, you are wrong. Also note that there are pauses between words in continuous speech.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I was stuck at the old times when Sphinx was yung. If you meant to say "there are no pauses", well that's not true. There are no audable pauses, but bounds exist and can be found with a bit of tweaking. And you can separate most of the words in this way.

Answer (score 3):

The language `voxforge_es_sphinx.transcription.test.lm` model you are using has "test" in the name, it is for testing purposes only. You can download more advanced model `es-20k.lm.gz` on our website [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish/).

Overall our Spanish model is quite basic and not very accurate, if you need a serious transcription you need to put a lot of effort to extend it.

Comment: Woah, now much better. It says:
"hola soy ingeniera de niñas", it misses one word and it sound ridiculous but it is much better! Thanks

Comment: The point is that I was unable to find models for Spanish aside the transcription test from voxforge. I am suprised of the current state of Spanish language model, being the third or second most spoken language in the world. I hope it continues improving :)

Comment: It does not decode informático because the word is missing in the model vocabulary. You can extend the model as described in [our tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallmadvanced). Work on Spanish is not very active because we are short of resources, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're right. I'll read your tutorial carefully and try to collaborate. Thanks again

Comment: I have uploaded an [updated model](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish/) just now, it is slightly more accurate.